# WebLogic datasource timeout

Tags: oracle-11g, weblogic

We have WebLogic 10 with some services running on it. One of our datasources started throwing timeout exceptions.

1. We set `Configuration -> Connection Pool -> Test table Name` to problem sql.
2. Restarted the server.
3. Run `Monitoring -> Test`.

It returned "everything is OK", but code is still throwing timeout exception.

How can it be?

Comment: Could be a query in the code ... ? Hard to tell without examining the error logs. Update your question with the full exception/relevant error log entries. If I'm not mistaken, `Test Table Name` defaults to `SQL SELECT 1 FROM DUAL` which is a 'dummy' table and will pass under most circumstances.

Comment: `Test Table Name` is set to problem sql: `SQL SELECT MOBIL_PHONE, OPER_ID ,ENABLED_DATE, DISABLED_DATE FROM SMS_INFO WHERE FLD_XXX=1234567890`